# How are keycodes decided?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a key with a keyCode of 1? I've tried researching but could not find anything. What decides the keycodes of each key? Just wondering...

```
var directions = {
    37: "left",
    38: "up",
    39: "right",
    40: "down",
    87:"up",
    68:"right",
    83:"down",
    65:"left"
};
```

Here it shows they keycodes of the left, right, up , down keys and w, a,s,d keys.

Comment: For letters: http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 1):

(revised)

The values for the legacy `keyCode` property of key board events is covered in the [UIEvents standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#legacy-KeyboardEvent). In particular

- `keyCode` is often the ASCII character code of the key pressed, especially for numeric digits and upper case letters.
- For lower case letters, `keyup` and `keydown` events return as`keyCode` value the ASCII code of the the letter in **upper case**, however -
- The `keycode` for lower case letters in `keypress` events is the ASCII code for the lower case letter.
- The `keyCode` for some keys, whose function is similar to that of an ASCII control character, is the control character's ASCII code.  E.G.  `TAB`, `CR`, `BS` or `ESC` ASCII codes are returned for the Tab, Enter,  Backspace or Esc labelled keys respectively.
- For non alphanumeric keys which have ASCII codes, `keyCode` may be obtained from key code tables shown in section [7.3.3](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#fixed-virtual-key-codes) or [7.3.4](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#optionally-fixed-virtual-key-codes). As a result their `keyCode` value isn't their ASCII value.
- If the key is not a printable character, it doesn't have an corresponding ASCII code and doesn't generate a key press event. This kind of key can use a `keyCode` value for `keydown` and `keyup` events from lower case letter codes (e.g. `Del` uses "d", function keys `F1` through `F11` use letters 'p' through 'z'), or from the  ASCII codes of characters whose keyCodes were taken from tables 7.3.3 or 7.3.4. linked above. E.G. `F12` uses the ASCII code for '{', `ArrowLeft` for '%' and `pageDown` for '"' as their `keyCode` value.)

  ---

  > How are keycodes decided?

The origin of `keyCode` values likely dates back to how scan codes from physical keyboards were sent to PCs as two bytes: one for the character pressed, and a status byte for modifier keys such as  Shift, Alt and others. This could be transformed by lookup tables for different keyboard layouts, but somewhere along the line at least one browser ended up with a `keyCode` solution to represent which key was pressed using an 8 bit value. Whatever the browser, other browsers would have followed suit to become "compatible".

Avoid using `keyCode` values in modern browsers unless support is required for older browsers which don't supply Unicode or [named-values](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents-key/#named-key-attribute-values) in the event object's `key` property.

---

> Is there a key with a keyCode of 1?

The ASCII code value of 1 is the ASCII `SOH` (start of heading) control character, and was generated on old ASCII keyboards by pressing the `Ctrl` and the `A` keys at the same time. There is no reference to it being generated by its own keyboard key (it doesn't have one), or being used for anything else in section 7 of the standard.

In short, it is not possible to generate a `keycode` value of `1` from the PC keyboard in a browser*. You could try detecting the `A` key with the `ctrlKey` event property set, but `Ctrl+A` is widely used in software for "select all".

<sub>* Under Windows, typing 0,0 and 1 on the keypad whilst holding down the ALT key produces an `SOH`character and is recognized by my editor as such. Trying this trick in Firefox didn't work and simply produced key events for `ALT`, `0`, `0` and `1`.</sub>

Comment: "the keycode returned for letter keys is always the ASCII code for the letter in upper case." nope. In `keypress` event it will be the cased one. Here are the algoritm**s** to determine the `.keyCode` value: https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#determine-keydown-keyup-keyCode

Comment: @Kaiido thanks - I was trying to avoid being specific about all the  messy details but rushed that one. Answer updated to include it.

Answer (score -4):

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_key_keycode.asp

utf8/16 has taken over ASCII as computing has adjusted to dealing with all the world's languages systematically.
https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_utf8.asp

Comment: Thanks for the questIon, I forgot to add the original link, now corrected

Comment: What does this have to do with keycodes, e.g., the question?